# How to import xls with assigning row to to table column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, excel, asp.net-4.0

I just want to make one xls column mapping feature so that user can directly import xls data to sql. Here is my code:

Here I have to assign the row no that was entered by users. What is the better way to assigning each destination column no from text box. Can some body help me?

### Update

i just made new code but this time lack of luck i have found with something not found column exception.

```
 protected void lbut_import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                if (FileUpload1.FileContent.Length > 0)
                {
                    string Foldername;
                    string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                    string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");
                    if (Extension == ".XLS" || Extension == ".XLSX" || Extension == ".xls" || Extension == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        Foldername = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Foldername + filename + Extension);
                        string conString = string.Empty;
                        switch (Extension)
                        {
                            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                                break;

                            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                              conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
                                break;
                        }
                        conString = string.Format(conString, Foldername + filename + Extension);

                        using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                        {
                            excel_con.Open();
                            string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

                            //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
                            dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[23] 
                                                        {new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("type_id", typeof(int)),
                                                         new DataColumn("Ownername",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("Ownermob",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("Room",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("Build",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("Road",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("Area",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("City",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("Phone",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("Mobile",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("Email",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("ContactPerson",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("ContactPersonmob",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("UserOFC",typeof(bool)),
                                                         new DataColumn("UserVAT",typeof(bool)),
                                                         new DataColumn("UserINV",typeof(bool)),
                                                         new DataColumn("UserNone",typeof(bool)),
                                                         new DataColumn("state_id",typeof(int)),
                                                         new DataColumn("country_id",typeof(int)),
                                                         new DataColumn("Remark",typeof(string)),
                                                         new DataColumn("Register_Date",typeof(DateTime)),
                                                         new DataColumn("User_id",typeof(string)),
                                                        });

                            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
                            {
                                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
                            }
                            excel_con.Close();
                            string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMConnectionString"].ToString();
                            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
                            {
                                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                                {
                                    //Set the database table name
                                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tbl_Party_master";

                                    //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("type_id",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col1.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col2.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Ownername",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col2.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col3.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Ownermob", dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col3.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col4.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Room",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col4.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col5.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Build", dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col5.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col6.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Road",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col6.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col7.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Area",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col7.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col8.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("City",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col8.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col9.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Phone", dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col9.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col10.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Mobile",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col10.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col11.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Email",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col11.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col12.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ContactPerson",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col12.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col13.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ContactPersonmob", dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col13.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col14.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UserOFC", dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col14.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col15.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UserVAT",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col15.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col16.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UserINV",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col16.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col17.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UserNone",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col17.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col18.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("state_id",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col18.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col19.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("country_id",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col19.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col20.Text.Trim())].ToString()))
                                    {
                                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Remark",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col20.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    }
                                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Register_Date",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col21.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("User_id",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col22.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                                    con.Open();
                                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                                    con.Close();
                                }
                            }
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
                            sb.Append("alert('");
                            sb.Append(dtExcelData.Rows.Count.ToString());
                            sb.Append(" Rows(s) are Inserted.');");
                            sb.Append("</script>");
                            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", sb.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                ibtnimexls_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
            }
    }
```

from the last line of column mapping i found error like :

```
Server Error in '/CRM' Application.

Cannot find column 23.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column 23.

Source Error: 


Line 3403:                                    }
Line 3404:                                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Register_Date",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col21.Text.Trim())].ToString());
Line 3405:                                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("User_id",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col22.Text.Trim())].ToString());
Line 3406:                                    con.Open();
Line 3407:                                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);

Source File: f:\CRM\Staff\Raise_Ticket.aspx.cs    Line: 3405 

Stack Trace: 


[IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column 23.]
   System.Data.DataColumnCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +95
   Staff_Raise_Ticket.lbut_import_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\CRM\Staff\Raise_Ticket.aspx.cs:3405
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

### Update

```
Column 'Name' does not allow DBNull.Value.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Column 'Name' does not allow DBNull.Value.

Source Error: 


Line 3407:                                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Register_Date", dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col21.Text.Trim())].ToString());
Line 3408:                                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("User_id", dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col22.Text.Trim())].ToString());
Line 3409:                                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
Line 3410:                                    con.Close();
Line 3411:                                }

Source File: f:\CRM\Staff\Raise_Ticket.aspx.cs    Line: 3409 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Column 'Name' does not allow DBNull.Value.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ConvertValue(Object value, _SqlMetaData metadata) +953277
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternal() +1393
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServer(Int32 columnCount) +762
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table, DataRowState rowState) +186
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table) +6
   Staff_Raise_Ticket.lbut_import_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\CRM\Staff\Raise_Ticket.aspx.cs:3409
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: does your "dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();" get values populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Upload and save the file
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

    string conString = string.Empty;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    switch (extension)
    {
        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;

    }
    conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
    using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        excel_con.Open();
        string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

        //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
        dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Salary",typeof(decimal)) });

        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
        {
            oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
        }
        excel_con.Close();

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tblPersons";

                //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "PersonId");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary", "Salary");
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also follow this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-SqlBulkCopy-to-import-Excel-SpreadSheet-data-into-SQL-Server-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) for more explaination

Comment: ur answer is verry help full. i have update my question and now i have just only little problems with boolean data. here when i check to boolean field checking error.

Comment: Yes i can, but at present I'm a bit busy, will answer you as soon as I'm done with my work. Hope that's ok with you.

Comment: try using "for(int i = 0; i< dt.Rows.Count-1;i++)" and let me know

Comment: The System.IndexOutOfRangeException exception indicates that you are accessing data table location with an invalid index. That is the index refers to an item that does not exist. In the code, you use data table location indexing when you access the data table. You attempt to access item with index 13 here.

Comment: if you can debug using break point and check when the position 13 comes its getting any value or not.

Comment: also check what is the count value of your data table "dt.Rows.Count"

Comment: it's 13 is it total available data from excel sheet.

Comment: and my excel sheet have all rows null with those columns UserOFC,UserVAT,UserINV,UserNone,state_id,country_id

Comment: this means your data table is just showing you the columns count, and giving you error because your excel is empty and is not able to find and data at that location. This is what happenning.

Comment: seems that "txt_col22" is not able to fetch value. can you check if you txt_col22 is not empty.

Comment: i have assigned it with required field also i put my code with if(Page.IsValid) clause. and my event get not fires.

Comment: it's getting value at debug time.

Comment: This error means there is no ITEM numbered 23 but you are converting into String / Int.. Null values cannot be converted into string....

There is some index issue,check that table have twenty Three items,and index start from 0,so for 23th use 22nd index.

Comment: your issue is something like this "new DataColumn("User_id",typeof(string))," this is created at an index location of 22 and while you are trying to map column at location index 23 in  "sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("User_id",dtExcelData.Columns[int.Parse(txt_col22.Text.Trim())].ToString());" so its not able to find the column "User_id" at location index 23, causing error to occur.

Comment: Can i do something wrong with range initialization.

Comment: i 'm tired now can u please fix it up with my code.

Comment: I cannot guess this prom from here, or fix it, If i can get hand on your project, I may try to. But need your project for that.

Comment: what the i do user entry mistakes i have to start with 0 with first text box now i fix it up thank u....when i start up with 1 last offcource have 23 so it's mistakes i column mapping have only 22 what is 23 at last.

Comment: Absolutely Right. Bang on the Target buddy. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Make sure the order of the fields in source and target are identical.

Comment: ya i pass identical starting from Name - 0 text box to User_id - 22

Comment: ya krunal did u get solution for that.

Comment: can i have to mention Id field which come from database auto increment field.